# How the Number of Expected bytes is calculated in Modbus RTU with Function Code 2

Tags: c, embedded, modbus

i am trying to find out how the Number of expected bytes is calculated with Function Code 2 in Modbus RTU.

I am querying registers from 0 to 71, but as a response i am getting expected bytes as 9
Below is the Query and response.

query : 33 02 00 00 00 47 3C 2A
resp : 33 02 **09** 00 08 00 FE FF FF FF FF 03 FA 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You queried for 71 bits, the response has 9 bytes containing 8 bits per byte, any excess bits are ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood now.